# how to count number of rows in gridview in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

As the question says, i wish to count the number of rows in gridview via JS. I am doing the way it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763641/asp-net-gridview-row-count-using-javascript) but that is not coming up correctly.

I have also tried different ways as:

```
 1. var rowscount = document.getElementByID('<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>').rows.length; 
 2. var rowscount = document.getElementByID("<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>").rows.length; 
 3. var rowscount = document.getElementByID('<%#Gridview1.ClientID%>').rows.length;
 4. var rowscount = document.getElementByID("<%#Gridview1.ClientID%>").rows.length;    
 5. var rowscount = document.getElementByID("Gridview1.ClientID").rows.length;
 6. var rowscount = document.getElementByID("Gridview1").rows.length;
```

**UPDATE** : Forgot to Mention: My gridview is inside updatepanel. Would that make any difference? 
What is the right statement?

Comment: Do you want to get the number of rows from server? Or do you need it necessarily to be computed by counting the elements in the DOM?

Comment: the reason i am not getting the row count correctly, from the JS link (as posted in question) is due to update panel which i have used on the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason: Because the grid is included in content page, the javascript had to be included under form tag. It runs well! Thanks all for inputs!!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the number of rows from the server one way would be to use:

```
var rowsCount = <%=GridView1.Rows.Count %>
```

It is also possible to send the data to JavaScript from codebehind.

Answer (score 3):

```
var GridId = "<%=Questionsedit.ClientID %>";            
var grid = document.getElementById(GridId);
rowscount = grid.rows.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable dt = //configure datasource here 
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
HiddenField1.value = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();

var  count = document.getElementById('HiddenField1');

alert(count.value);
```

This seems to have worked for someone in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1201659.aspx/1) forum post.

Comment: I am caounting the rows in window onload function from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/SelectingAllCheckBoxes.aspx
Would that make a difference?

Comment: It also threws the error of "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but it appears to have worked for the people concerned. Try taking a look at the whole post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1201659.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

You could set the RowStyle.CssClass property for the gridview and count them using jQuery.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ...>
   <RowStyle CssClass="gridrow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

This will render the grid rows with the class specified.

```
<tr class="gridrow">
  <td>row data here</td>
</tr>
```

Then you can count the rows using the class selector

```
var rowscount = $(".gridrow").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify that,

```
var gridViewRowCount = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").rows.length;
alert(gridViewRowCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var rowscount = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").length;
```

or see:
[How to count the rows in a gridview in asp.net using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456723/how-to-count-the-rows-in-a-gridview-in-asp-net-using-jquery)

Comment: This always gives me 1 whereas Răzvan Panda's solution gives me the correct count.

Comment: Correction: This always gives me 0 or 1 whereas Răzvan Panda's solution gives me the correct count.