# How to validate gridview when Clicking on Save button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, customvalidator, client-side-validation

I have a gridview in a form that contains a Save ImageButton. I would like to create a Client-side CustomValidator that checks whether the grid is empty or not. If it is empty then I would like to throw an error message to the user.

This is my code. In the "Save_btn_Click" event, I check if the page is Valid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      OnRowCancelingEdit="gridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                      OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand" 
                      OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound" 
                      OnRowEditing="gridView_RowEditing"
                      OnRowUpdating="gridView_RowUpdating" 
 >....</GridView>

<asp:CustomValidator id="cvFabricCollection" runat="server"                                                 
ErrorMessage="Please enter at least one row"
ControlToValidate="gridView"
ValidationGroup="MyGroup"
ClientValidationFunction ="ValidateGrid">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:ImageButton ID="Save_btn" 
ImageUrl="images/save.gif"
runat="server"
CausesValidation="True" 
ValidationGroup="MyGroup"
OnClick="Save_btn_Click"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function ValidateGrid(sender, args)
{
    var rowscount = document.getElementByID(<%=MyGridView.ClientID%>).rows.length;
    alert(rowscount);
    if(rowscount <= 1)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code to get row count of your gridview:

```
var rowscount = document.getElementByID(<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>).rows.length;
if(rowcount >0)
{
   alert("your message");
}
```

references:
[ASP.NET GridView row count using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763641/asp-net-gridview-row-count-using-javascript)

[How to count the rows in a gridview in asp.net using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456723/how-to-count-the-rows-in-a-gridview-in-asp-net-using-jquery)

Comment: I updated my JavaScript (view original post) using the code you have provided, but it's still not working... While I was debugging the code, I noticed that it went first to my "Save_btn_Click" function, and then to the "ValidateGrid" function, but it doesn't seem to do anything as I'm not getting any alert messages... Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: @Joe S: please try it like: create a separate function of javascript with no parameters, place rowcount code in it and call it from you SAVEBUTTON's onClientClick event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function PassengerGrid(source, args) {
    var Grid1 = document.getElementById("<%=GridviewPassenger.ClientID%>");
    if (Grid1 == null) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else if (Grid1.rows.length <= 0)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a description to your answer, rather than just posting code.